# Finding the coefficients of a quadratic equation giving one point and open interval

Tags: polynomials

Here is my question

The quadratic function $f$ is negative only on the open interval $(−2, 1/4 )$ and its graph passes through the point$ (−1, −5)$. Determine the coefficients of f and sketch its graph.

Please explain how you got your answer and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=\kappa(x+2)(x-\frac{1}{4})$ then $f(-1)=-5$ to deduce $\kappa$

Comment: Please explain what the question means. Can you please provide more detail? Also, I need to know all 3 coefficients, not just one.Thanks

Comment: $f$ is quadratic and change sign at $-2$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ therefore the two values are roots of $f$ and the claim follows.

Comment: I am a beginner. Please explain more. Thanks

Comment: Look, can you trip from Los Angeles to Paris without crossing water? Los Angeles is the positive sign, Paris the negative and water is the « zero ». Since your function is positive before -2 and negative after -2, so $f(-2)=0$, hence it must be a (x-(-2)) as a factor of f. Same argument at 1/4. You must know that every quadratic function can be written as a(x-root1)(x-root2).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I still wonder how I can get the other two.